# r error recursive indexing failed at level 2 matrix

Tags: r, recursion, matrix

Rows of a Matrix book store the latitude, longitude at column 2 and 3 and column 6 to n stores the indices of the points which are within 600 m to the ith one. In the below code, I am trying to check if any points in ith row is within a range to the jth point. If so, then I am appending the indices of both the rows. But while doing so, I am getting an error `Error in *tmp*[[j]] : recursive indexing failed at level 2`
This is the data set

```
   vehicle_id  longt  latit  date   B B B B B B B B B B B B B B B
1    19967   86.2885 23.8210   27   3 1 2 6 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
2    19967   86.2891 23.8200   27   2 2 6 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
3    19967   86.5343 23.8254   27   1 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
4    19967   86.7273 23.8200   27   1 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
5    19967   86.1362 23.7538   28   1 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
6    19967   86.2839 23.8212   28   1 6 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

  B B B B B B B B B B B B B
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
6 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

I wanted to know why I am getting this errror and how could I resolve it.???/

```
S=0
for(i in 1:(nrow(book)-1))
{        

  if( book[i, 1] != book[i+1,1]  )
  {
    next
  }





 for(j in i:nrow(book))
  {  

if(  book[i,1]!=book[j,1])
{    
  break           }


if(  book[i,1]==book[j,1] &  (book[i,5] > 2 ))
     {  for( k in 7:(5+book[i,5]))



  if(distm (c(book[book[i,k],3], book[book[i,k],2]), c(book[j,3], book[j,2]), fun = distHaversine) < 600)               
  {     S=book[i,5]+book[j,5]
    if (S-k > 0)
    {   B<- matrix(0,nrow(book),(S-k))
    book <- cbind(book,B)
    book[i,5]=book[i,5]+book[j,5]       
    } 


    book[i,(6+book[i,5]):((6+book[i,5])+book[j,5])] <- book[j,(6:(5+book[j,5]))]



  }



}


  }
 for( k in 7:(5+book[i,5]))

 {  if(i!=book[i,k])    
 {book[book[i,k],1]=0;
 }
 }






}
```

`

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. This question would benefit from a dataset that we could try the code on. Could you use `dput(head(book))` and edit that in your post? This gives us the first 6 rows of your dataset. Make sure that the error also arises with those 6 rows, though.

Comment: Hi, I have now attached the dataset.!! Thanks!