# Recursive indexing failed at level 2

Tags: r, list, recursion, lm, sapply

I'm trying to do repeated random sub-sampling for a linear model in R. To achieve this, I first create a list of data.table indices to be used for training the model and then use `lm` for that specific subset. Below is sample code using `diamonds` dataset from `ggplot2`:

```
library(data.table)
library(caTools)
library(ggplot2)
rm(list = ls())
dat <- as.data.table(diamonds)[1:5000,]

n <- 20
dat_list <- lapply(1:n, function(z) return(sample.split(dat$carat, SplitRatio = 3/4)) )
```

Then I `sapply` to get the slope for different linear-fit models:

```
coefs <- sapply(1:n, function(z){
  m <- lm(price ~ carat, data = dat[dat_list[[z]],])
  return(unname(m$coefficients[2]))
})
```

Oddly enough, this worked when I last tried this but today I got the below error:

*Error in dat_list[[z]] : recursive indexing failed at level 2*

The code appears to work if I first save the indices to another variable:

```
coefs <- sapply(1:n, function(z){
  train_indices <- dat_list[[z]]
  m <- lm(price ~ carat, data = dat[train_indices,])
  return(unname(m$coefficients[2]))
})
```

I've seen other questions on SO: [Getting error "recursive indexing failed at level 2" in R when trying to recurse through list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38979833/getting-error-recursive-indexing-failed-at-level-2-in-r-when-trying-to-recurse), [r error recursive indexing failed at level 2 matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37431010/r-error-recursive-indexing-failed-at-level-2-matrix) and [Recursive Index Failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37745852/recursive-index-failed) but they do not seem to answer my question?

Why such behaviour, especially considering that this worked in the past? Am I missing something?

Comment: Probably yesterday you changed your `dat` to a dataframe instead of a datatable. Seems to work. Do you really need a datatable?

Comment: That shouldn't be the case, the first line of my code loads the usual packages (data.table, ggplot2 etc.). I use `data.table` because it's faster (i have a lot of observations) and I find it much easier to its `[i, j, by]` format

Comment: The fact that you load the packages doesn't mean that the functions will work with datatables as they work with dataframes. Please try to change `dat` to dataframe when you create it and check if the code works. The objective is to find why this code breaks and then to adjust it using a datatable structure.

Comment: You're correct. It works if I don't use datatable and I will change other parts of my code accordingly. However, as per the documentation *Since  a data.table is a data.frame, it is  compatible  with R functions  and  packages that accept only data.frames.*